# Setting a permanent default communications device in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, sound-card

I have three monitors which are not always on when I use the computer. Each of the monitors also has it's own speaker system. They all use DP cable to connect them to the computer via nVidia GFX card.

I have a dedicated sound card which I use for all of my outbound audio. I've set it as default device and default communications device on the playback tab of the sound option in the control panel.

However, each time I turn on one of the monitors, all of my sound gets redirected to that monitor, despite the fact I've previously disabled this  audio device and set another as the default.

How do I tell Windows 10 to stop being a smartass and just do what I told it to do?

I want my audio to go to a device I specified, no matter how many other audio devices I connect to my computer, until the moment where I myself change these settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one.

When you connect and disconnect a displayport device, windows installs and uninstalls the hardware.

You haven't actually specified the brand and model of the monitor, so I cannot look up which one you have and if it has the option to disable the speakers, which would definitely solve your issue.

That said, if you enable the monitor, make sure it is fully working and not disabled, and you then set the default audio source, windows should remember this when you turn off and on the monitor.

However, if you use an USB soundcard too, then it may break because when that device is turned off, it also gets uninstalled so when windows does not have a soundcard it can find, it will switch to whatever is available.

Lastly, in Windows 10, you can quickly switch to a different audio device by pressing the sound icon in the taskbar once, so the volume meter shows up, then press the name of your sound device so a dropdown list shows up with all your devices, and select the correct one.

Comment: I have two LG 27UD68P-B and an Acer XB271HU (I'll most likely swap LGs for two Acers). I haven't found a way to disable the sound in the OSD of any of them. USB sound card is rarely plugged out, so the method you suggested might work.

Comment: Despite it being plugged out or not, an USB device is being installed and uninstalled at windows start and shutdown. If for some reason windows sees the monitor but not the usb soundcard, it will switch already. This problem will definitely go away if you switch from a usb device to an internal soundcard.

Comment: Well, that's just not an option. Maybe I could create some kind of startup task/script?

Comment: Not sure... but this is as far support I can give. At least you are a step ahead in why this is happening and how to potentially fix it.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. You at least confirmed this was a real problem, that the issue wasn't me being stupid.